# How to display Original image from folder codeignihter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to display image from its original folder. I want to display the original image in a 1366x768 window.

When I change

```
<?php $width = 1366;$height = 768; ?>
```

height in this line, it automaticaly display crop the image in this height and width.

```html
<div class="white_box">
<div class="box-body">
<span class="hide WallHashID"><?php echo $wallpaper->wallpaper_hash; ?></span>
<?php $width = 1366;
$height = 768; ?>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="wallpaper_image">
        <img class="thumbnail img-responsive"
             style="width:100%; height:auto; display:block; max-width:<?php echo $width; ?>px;max-height: <?php echo $height; ?>px;"
             src="<?php echo $this->image_workshop->crop_image(ORIGINALS_FOLDER_WF . '/' . $wallpaper->wallpaper_image_path, $width, $height, $wallpaper->wallpaper_crop_position, 'thumbnail'); ?>"
             alt="<?php echo $wallpaper->wallpaper_name; ?>">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Well, you are **cropping** it with `$this->image_workshop->crop_image`.

Comment: can you please tell me how to display just image from folder using wallpaper_hash;

Comment: In case you are using absolute server path, you should use link i.e. `base_url('uploads/myimage.jpg')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to use `$this->image_workshop->crop_image` function, or any other function to process the image. You can use the absolute path of the image and style it with css or with html attributes *height* and *width*. For example style it with **css**:

```
<img class="thumbnail img-responsive"
             style="width:<?php echo $width;?>px; height:<?php echo $height;?>px; display:block; max-width:<?php echo $width; ?>px;max-height: <?php echo $height; ?>px;"
             src="<?php echo ORIGINALS_FOLDER_WF . '/' . $wallpaper->wallpaper_image_path ; ?>"
             alt="<?php echo $wallpaper->wallpaper_name; ?>">
```

Or with html tag attributes:

```
<img class="thumbnail img-responsive"
                 width="<?php echo $width;?>" 
                 height="<?php echo $height;?>"
                 src="<?php echo ORIGINALS_FOLDER_WF . '/' . $wallpaper->wallpaper_image_path ; ?>"
                 alt="<?php echo $wallpaper->wallpaper_name; ?>">
```

The down side is that you would load the full size image in the browser, where it gets resized. If you care about the information size for the picture, you should create the thumbnails versions as you upload the original. Then use thumbnail version of the image.

Answer (score 1):

simply:

`<img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>your folder name /<?php echo $wallpaper->wallpaper_image_path; ?>">`

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem.